# Rails ActiveRecord object lookup with dynamically generated content in partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, syntax

In my app users have lists and list_items (list_items link the products they add to their appropriate list). I have a product search modal that returns a list of products each with a product_id attribute. I would like to conditionally display a button (either ADD or ADDED) based on whether the user already has the product in their list or not.

The issue is using {raw-product_id} variable that is passed in from the search with the ActiveRecord object lookup. If I manually input an integer, it works fine, but the variable that is used looks like it's a string, and even with to_i appended, doesn't work when using: `- if current_user.list_items.where(product_id: '{raw-product_id}'.to_i).exists?` Relevant lines of code near the bottom.

code:

```
            -# = form_tag main_app.products_path(), method: :post do
            = form_tag main_app.list_items_path, data: { passthru: current_user.nil?, remote: true } do |f|
                = hidden_field_tag :success, 'back'
                = hidden_field_tag :list_id, args[:list].try(:id) || '0'
                .product_picker_inner
                    .product_picker_body

                        .product_picker_details
                            .product_picker_details_default
                                = hidden_field_tag :product_id, '{raw-product_id}'
                                = hidden_field_tag :added_from, 'search'
                                %h4.text-center
                                    {escaped-title}
                                .text-center.product_picker_category
                                    %span
                                        {escaped-category}
                                .product_picker_content
                                    .row
                                        .col-xs-12.col-md-6.product_picker_avatar6
                                            %img.img.img-responsive.center-block{ src: '#{raw-avatar}' }
                                            -# .rectangle-avatar.contain-image{ style: 'background-image: url("{encoded-avatar}")' }
                                        .col-xs-12.col-md-6.product_picker_description
                                            {escaped-description}
                                        .col-xs-12.col-md-6
                                            .text-center{ style: 'margin:1em 2em 0.3em 0' }
                                                price:
                                                %b
                                                    {raw-price_formatted}
                                    .row{ style: 'padding: 1em 0 0 0;' }
                                        .col-xs-12
                                            .fancy-span{ style: 'font-size: 0.8em' }
                                                %span Tell us about this product
                                            = text_area_tag :comment, '', class: 'form-control'
                                .text-center.product_picker_controlls
                                    - if current_user.list_items.where(product_id: '{raw-product_id}'.to_i).exists?
                                        = button_tag 'ADDED', type: 'submit', class: 'btn btn-danger btn-lg t03e', id: 'product-{raw-product_id}'
                                        -# %a.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg.t03e{ href: "#{products_path( list_id: args[:list].try(:id) || '0', success: 'back' )}&u={raw-id}", data: { method: :post } }
                                            ADDED
                                    - else
                                        = button_tag 'ADD', type: 'submit', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg t03e', id: 'product-{raw-product_id}'
                                        -# %a.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg.t03e{ href: "#{products_path( list_id: args[:list].try(:id) || '0', success: 'back' )}&u={raw-id}", data: { method: :post } }
                                            ADD
                        .product_picker_loading_overlay
                            %div{ style: 'position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 0;line-height: 1.1em;right: 0;text-align: center;font-size: 40px;margin: -20px 0 0 0;' }
                                %i.fa.fa-circle-o-notch.fa-spin
            .text-center{ style: '' }
                %a{ href: '#', 'data-dismiss' => 'modal' }
                    CLOSE
```

Comment: Also, upon moving the ActiveRecord lookup to a model method, I noticed that the method gets called as soon as the page is rendered, but before the search is made. I somehow need to call the method only when the search is made and the partial is opened.

Comment: I've found that the partial is loading the variables {raw-product_id} from json, parsed from a jbuilder file. I haven't dealt with these before - it looks like I need a way to re-render the partial, or at least the buttons, when the XHR request is returned.

Answer (score 0):

In more closely examining the code, I found that there was a javascript file that replaced all instances of {raw-attribute} with the proper values, so this DOM manipulation was not reaching the ERB itself. My solution was to add the button text and button class directly to the JSON itself, and then add those attributes in the HAML.

new json in the jbuilder file:

```
json.in_list @list.list_items.where(product_id: product[:product_retailer].try(:product_id)).exists? ? 'ADDED' : 'ADD'
json.button_class @list.list_items.where(product_id: product[:product_retailer].try(:product_id)).exists? ? 'btn-danger' : 'btn-primary'
```

new haml:

```
.text-center.product_picker_controlls
    = button_tag '{raw-in_list}', type: 'submit', class: 'btn btn-lg t03e {raw-button_class}', id: 'product-{raw-product_id}'
    -# %a.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg.t03e{ href: "#{products_path( list_id: args[:list].try(:id) || '0', success: 'back' )}&u={raw-id}", data: { method: :post } }
        '{raw-in_list}'
```